# How to convert mat(OpenCV) to image(JavaFX)?

Tags: java, opencv, javafx

How to convert mat(OpenCV) to image(JavaFX)?
I think this isn't not best method:

```
MatOfByte byteMat = new MatOfByte();
Highgui.imencode(".bmp", mat, byteMat);
return new Image(new ByteArrayInputStream(byteMat.toArray()));
```

P.S.

```
Image - import javafx.scene.image.Image;
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be this.I do not remember the source from where I got this:-

```
private Image mat2Image(Mat frame)
{
    int type = BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY;
    if ( frame.channels() > 1 ) {
        type = BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR;
    }
    int bufferSize = frame.channels()*frame.cols()*frame.rows();
    byte [] b = new byte[bufferSize];
    frame.get(0,0,b); // get all the pixels
    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(frame.cols(),frame.rows(), type);
    final byte[] targetPixels = ((DataBufferByte) image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
    System.arraycopy(b, 0, targetPixels, 0, b.length);
    return SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(image,null);

}
```

There may be a way to make it neater using the Converters class from Opencv along with JDK8. I will update this if I find any such thing.

Answer (score 0):

Paritosh, the issue with your method is that it only applies to the Mats with the type of `CvType.CV_8U` or `CvType.CV_8S`, since those Mats can be contained in a byte array. If the type of the Mat is, lets say, `CvType.CV_32F`, you would need a float array to hold the data. The float array cannot be System.arraycopied into a `byte[] targetPixels` array.