# how to display IplImage in an javafx imageview

Tags: image, opencv, javafx, javacv, iplimage

I am trying to display IplImage on imageview in application.
But Imageview_id.setImage() allows only Image obj as parameter.
Is there is another method to display iplImage in imageview ?
or
How to convert IplImage to Image?

Comment: Please add some code examples to show what you have tried so far.

Comment: original.setStyle("-fx-background-image: url('img1');");or
original.setImage(img1);

Comment: check my code at [link](https://github.com/mahajandhiraj/MouseEye)

Comment: Possible duplicated: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29120869/how-to-convert-matopencv-to-imagejavafx